# Remove horizontal scrollbar under fixed columns DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm combining a complex header and fixed columns:
1) complex header: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html
2) fixed columns: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html
It works fine but is there a way to remove the scrollbar from the fixed header columns? I've outlined the bit I'd like to remove.

Basically, I want to make it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/8c5jgs4b/ but with DataTables and complex header.
Here's my own fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omgLswq6/151/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#compareResults').DataTable({
         paging: false,
         ordering: false,
         info: false,
         scrollX: true,
         fixedColumns: {
             leftColumns: 5
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Still need help with this.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this by changing the overflow style to be hidden in the fixed left column container:

```css
.DTFC_LeftBodyLiner {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="DTFC_LeftBodyLiner">
  <table class="foo_datatable">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```